# Converting Oracle SQL join query into MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join

Given the following join in Oracle Pl/SQL:

```
select a.field1, b.field1, b.field2
from table_a a, table_b b
where a.field2 = b.field3;
```

When executed this code in MySQL, it takes a really long time to do the task while in Pl/SQL it takes no time. The tables are the same in the two environments. No fields are indexed.

Is there a difference between the joins in the two dialects? What would be the correct translation of this in standard SQL?

Comment: it's not truly `JOIN`, this approach is more slower as `JOIN` you can use `select a.field1, b.field1, b.field2 from table_a a inner join table_b b where a.field2 = b.field3`

Comment: So you mean that the 'join...on' would give the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not cope with having no indexes. Oracle can do a hash join and still be fast. Add indexes on the join columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need indexes in MySql to avoid the problem that you are facing.